# Solve inverse log + constant

Tags: logarithms, inverse

Is it possible to solve for `b` in the following?

```
a = log2(b + c)
```

For example:

```
3.907 = log2(b + 10)
b = 5
```

Comment: How about $b=2^{a}-c$ ?

Comment: $b=2^a-c$ ................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
a &=& \log_2(b+c) \\
2^a &=& b+c \\
2^a-c &=& b \\
b &=& 2^a-c
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$y = \log_2(x) \Leftrightarrow 2^y=x $$